# How do I bind the textbox to a dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a dropdownlist that allows user to select the `SupplierName`. It worked.
The problem is that I need the textbox to be filled with corresponding `SupplierEmail`:

```
protected void ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  FetchData();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("ePMT_SP_BindSupplierDDLToTextBox", con);
    cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SupplierEmail",ddlSupplier.SelectedItem));            
    // txtSupplierEmail.Text = dt.Rows[0]["SupplierEmail"].ToString(); 
    // SqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader();                
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        txtSupplierEmail.Text = row["SupplierEmail"].ToString();
    }
}
```

The stored procedure for `ePMT_SP_BindSupplierDDLToTextBox`:

```
SELECT SupplierEmail 
FROM dbo.EPMT_MASTER_SUPPLIER 
WHERE SupplierName = @SupplierName
```

The stored procedure for `ePMT_SP_BindSupplier`:

```
SELECT SupplierName 
FROM SSMC_EPMT.dbo.EPMT_MASTER_SUPPLIER 

private void BindDropdownlist()
{
    DataTable dtSupplier = eBiz.BindSupplier();
    ddlSupplier.DataSource = dtSupplier;
    ddlSupplier.DataTextField = "SupplierName";
    ddlSupplier.DataValueField = "SupplierName";
    ddlSupplier.DataBind();
    ddlSupplier.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
}

<label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputRefNo">
     Vendor :<span style="color: red">*</span>
</label>
<div class="input-group col-md-8">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSupplier" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:DropDownList>
</div>
```

Comment: Question and code snippet are totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
con.Open();
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("ePMT_SP_BindSupplierDDLToTextBox", con);
cmd1.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@SupplierEmail",ddlSupplier.SelectedItem));
SqlDataReader datareader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
while(datareader.Read())
{
    txtSupplierEmail.Text = datareader["SupplierEmail"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I have to create another stored procedure and then linked it to the dropdownlist name :

```
 String sql = "SELECT * from dbo.EPMT_MASTER_SUPPLIER where SUPPLIERName = '" + ddlSupplier.SelectedItem.Text + "' ";
```

before drawing out all the textbox that I want to pop up the data.